KOMA Script (scrlttr2) and tabularray - compatibility issues?
A M(N)WE of what has once been a rather complex table:
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ }
\begin{tblr}[long]{l}
test \\
\end{tblr}
\end{letter}
\end{document}

Compiling this results in:
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'table' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \end
        {tblr}

If I omit [long] or change the document class to scrartcl everything is fine, but in the real-world example, I need this configuration. I found exactly nothing to this issue; when asking ChatGPT I got a hint that scrlttr2 and tabularray are incompatible - which in fact seems to be the case, but I could not find anything to support this claim either (and I can't believe I am the first one to try this combination).
So how to fix this?

Likely ChatGPT queried its “knowledge” base and associated problems with packages and classes with “incompatibility”. And, lo and behold, upon asking humans, you got a thorough and well informed answer. I've seen ChatGPT answering that a prime number can be the sum of three primes, for example 2+3+5=11. This for attesting the usefulness of the tool when trying to solve a real problem.

@egreg I always try to gather info elsewhere before asking here (which is less embarrassing). ChatGPT normally gives either useful hints or blatant nonsense; I was surprised to receive an answer which seemed to be correct but still did not lead me to useful information.

Unfortunately you've cut of the most important line of the error message …
scrlttr2 does not provide floats. So the counter table is not defined and you get the error message:
LaTeX Error: No counter 'table' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \end
        {tblr}

But for several years KOMA-Script also provides a solution for those, who need tables, figures or even sections etc. in letters. Use either another KOMA-Script class and additionally package scrletter or the wrapper class scrletter which is scrartcl with package scrletter and some default (like the font size) changed to the default of scrlttr2:
\documentclass{scrletter}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
\opening{Hello,}
\begin{tblr}[long]{lcr}
Alpha & Beta & Gamma
\end{tblr}
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}


See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about class scrlttr2 and package scrletter or class scrletter and the differences to class scrlttr2.

Actually the missing line was there, but i accidentally deleted the line break after the markup. It did not give me any insight though, as I have no idea about "counters" or else; I use LaTeX kind of like HTML, as a markup language, but without ambitions to program it. Anyway, your solution is exactly what I was looking for.
